# Problems with limiting rows in database with if condition

Tags: spring-boot, rest, jpa, h2

I am trying to limit my database to store only 10 beers... I tried to use if statement like:

```
for (int i=0; i<beers.length; i++) {
        if (beers.length != 0)
            beerRepository.save(beers[i]);
        else if (beers.length == 10)
            throw new RuntimeException("Database full!");
    }
```

But for some reasons it doesn't work. I can still store more than 10 beers in database. Any suggestions where I am wrong?

Comment: you can remove `if (beers.length != 0)` because it is always true

Comment: Yeah I already tried that, but it is still the same

Comment: Every time you call this piece of code (the for loop) will save some beers in you database. The way you are trying will only limit the saving of 10 beers per call of the for loop. Is that your intention?

Comment: what are the `beers`, is that coming from the database or from some other place ?

Comment: Let's say the beer's length is 12. so, can you tell me what your code should do for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if...else if` statement is not correct. Even if `beers.length` is 10, your first `if` statement is executed because you just check the `beers.length` to be non-zero. So beers are always persisted.

Your intentions on what to do are still vague however if you wanted some code inside that for loop to save the first 10 beer records of the `beers` array would be:

```
for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
    beerRepository.save(beers[i]); 
}
```

If you want to check your database if 10 beer records are already saved, you can ask your repo with:

```
beerRepository.count();
```

And you could use this prior your `for` loop to check if database is full.
e.g.

```
if (beerRepository.count() >= 10) {
    throw new RuntimeException("Database full!");
} else {
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
       beerRepository.save(beers[i]); 
    }
}
```